# Not getting output using argprase

Tags: python, argparse

I was following along with a video discussing the basics of using argparse by calculating a Fibonacci number. I typed the code into my pycharm editor and when I run the code I don't get any output. It completes with the following message "Process finished with exit code 0". Thoughts?

```
import argparse
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
def Main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("num", help="Fibonacci number to calculate", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    result = fib(args.num)
    print("The " + str(args.num) + "th fib number is " + str(result))
if __name__ == '__Main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: How exactly are you "run the code"?  Do you know how to provide commandline arguments when using `pycharm`?  Or even know what we mean by that?

Comment: While learning it's a good idea to include a `print(args`)` statement right after the `parse_args`.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj and thanks for the comments! Yes, I added the commandline arguments when using pychart. Also, thanks for the print(args) tip. I will use that as I continue to enhance the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```py
import argparse

def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("num", help="Fibonacci number to calculate", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    result = fib(args.num)
    print("The " + str(args.num) + "thw fib number is " + str(result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When run as a program, `__name__` will be set to`__main__` and not `__Main__`. Please note also that function and variable names should always start with lowercase letters. And leave a blank line between functions, that makes the code more readable !

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
if __name__ == '__Main__':
```

When you are running the script, `__name__` magic variable is set to `__main__` with lowercase `m`. Fix it and it would work.

This great answer has plenty of details about magic variables and what does `if __name__ == '__main__':` line do:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/12118546

Comment: Thanks @Roman for the quick help and link!! That solved the problem and I am able to move on with adding more functionality to the program.